# Cognos External Report Server process BIBusTKServerMain & BmtMDProviderMain cannot be started

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

We have installed Cognos 12 on Ubuntu 22.04 server. While starting the Cognos service we are getting below errors.

```
External Report Server process BIBusTKServerMain cannot be started
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin/BIBusTKServerMain" (in directory "/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

```
External Report Server process BmtMDProviderMain cannot be started
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin/BmtMDProviderMain" (in directory "/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

However, as checked both the files are present in the location. ldd BIBusTKServerMain and ldd BmtMDProviderMain is giving output as not a dynamic executable, but if we do ./BIBusTKServerMain getting same no such file or directory error.

We added $LD_LIBRARY_PATH as /opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin64:/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin as suggested by IBM documentation but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was library dependency and Report Server Execution mode.

Library details are available [here](https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=BE7FAD963E12495BABC5189F9A8A5BFA&osPlatform=Linux#!).

Change the report server execution mode to 64 bit.